# Find property associated with PropertyDataFilter1D

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have a PropertyDataFilter1D input by the user.  How do I figure out which pillar grid property is associated with that filter?  The filter contains a PropertyVersionBase member, but I don't know how to look up the property with that.

Comment: Which version of Ocean are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem here: Ocean API allows you to create a PropertyDataFilter1D from a PropertyVersion, whereas native filters in Petrel are created from a property. And, Ocean doesn't expose any reference to the Petrel property. Other words, if you have two filters for two different porosity properties, but both properties are based on the same Porosity template, from the Ocean site it will be the same Porosity PropertyVersion (Template) for the both filters.